# How to add FontAwesome to Interface Builder's font list?

Tags: xcode, uibutton, interface-builder, xcode4.6, font-awesome

FontAwesome is installed in Font Book:

[image]

However, it's not shown on Interface Builder's font list:

[image]

How can I select FontAwesome as the font for a  `UIButton`?

Answer (score 1):

try this method

```
1. Add your font to project resources
2. In plist file
```

[image]

```
3. myButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"yourFontName" size:yourFontSize];
```